# CPLEX take long time to start

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I have a huge linear model in CPLEX which is written in Microsoft Visual C++. 
After a call to `cplex.solve()`, there is no progress for a very long time. Nothing will be displayed for 5 minutes. Then, the number of threads will be displayed and the presolve time is less than 1 seconds.  All of the rows and columns are eliminated and solve time is less than 1 second.

My log file is as follows:

```
Warning:  Output names have been modified to conform to LP format.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 8 threads for concurrent optimization.
Tried aggregator 1 time.
LP Presolve eliminated 283559 rows and 283572 columns.
All rows and columns eliminated.
Presolve time = 0.48 sec. (516.10 ticks)
```

or one else when I'm adding another column in column generation is

```
Warning:  Output names have been modified to conform to LP format.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 8 threads for concurrent optimization.
Iteration log . . .
Iteration:     1   Scaled dual infeas =           224.981132
Iteration:    13   Dual objective     =      25519782.182497
Iteration:  3159   Dual objective     =      30679377.244649
Barrier solved model.
```

Why is it taking so long to start? 
What is that Warning?

To be sure, I exported the model and imported it into another project, solved, and whole process was less than 2 seconds.  So, during that 4 minutes it does not do aggregation or presolve.

Moreover, I checked the perfomance with CODEXL and I found two functions in the dll which are used a lot and I have no idea about them: CPXLkillpnorms, CPXEgeneric_unlock, cplex1261.dll!+0x2627a2

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Mehdi

Answer (score 1):

I have no insights about your performance issue, but I can provide some information about the secondary question within your question regarding the warning `Output names have been modified to conform to LP format.`  This warning means that variable and constraint names in your model have been modified to use suffixes of the form "#number", as described in [this IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21512617).

The LP format has some surprising restrictions on variable and constraint names.  In particular, variable and constraint names may not contain certain characters (including ^, *, [, ], or a space) and they may not start with the characters e or E.  If the model contains any such violations of the LP format, the corresponding variable or constraint names will have #number suffixes.   Although the naming requirements are apparently related to the LP format, I have seen that the #number names are also used in other output formats, such as SAV.

It may be possible, by renaming the components of your model, to get rid of this error message.  [This post on IBM developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014680905) describes how one user was able to do so by renaming a variable from `excessVarForConstraint` to `dddVarForConstraint`.

However, I suspect that the explanation provided by IBM is incomplete.  Even for OPL models in which I have removed all offending characters from the variable and constraint names (technically, within OPL, "constraint labels"), the error message *still* appears and the LP output has #number suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the performance issue, here's one thing you can try:

```
IloNum start = cplex.getCplexTime();
cplex.solve();
std::cout << "Elapsed: " << (cplex.getCplexTime() - start) << std::endl;
```

That is, make sure that it is actually the `solve()` function that consumes the time.  Compare the printed time with the time displayed in the CPLEX log (e.g., from the CPLEX interactive).  If the difference is huge, then the culprit may be delayed [model extraction](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/APIs/Cpp/extract_model.html?lang=en).

If it does look like there is a performance issue, it's best to go through the official [IBM support](https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/product/websphere/ibm_ilog_cplex_optimization_studio?productContext=-568455760) channels.  If you're using CPLEX through the [Academic Initiative](http://www-304.ibm.com/ibm/university/academic/pub/page/ban_prescriptive_analytics), you can use the [developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059) forum for support.